# Pure CSS if/ else statement involving custom unit of size variables

Tags: css, variables, conditional-statements, viewport-units

I want to solve my issue only using **pure CSS**.
Here's the problematic code that I have:

```
@if (100vh > 830px) {:root { --cwv:100vh;}}
@else {:root { --cwv: 830px;}}
```

What I'm trying to do: if browser window size is smaller than 830px, the "- -cvw" (custom width variable/ unit) should be **relative** <sub>(another problem that my code probably has)</sub> to 830px rather than 100vw <sub>(built-in viewport "vertical width" unit)</sub>, as the elements on the page get too small.

I know I can use multiple other ways to solve this problem using other languages, but I am just wondering how to make the CSS code work - as it is supposed to - according to the places that I have researched:

- [CSS custom properties (variables)](https://blog.gospodarets.com/css_properties_in_depth) - states that variables are declared in the following manner: `:root{--variable-name: variable-value;}`
- [CSS Conditionals (if/ else statements)](http://gridstylesheets.org/guides/ifelse/)

What am I doing wrong? I expect that I have multiple syntax errors in my code <sub>(that I've provided above)</sub> too... :/

Comment: CSS does not have if/then statements. What it has is multiple rules that are selected by selectors and/or media queries. Have you heard of media queries? If not, go back and brush up on your basic CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) `max-width`.
Example:

Default `--cwx` set to viewport width:

```
:root{
  --cwv: 100vw;
}
```

In case where viewport width is lesser or equal `830px`, set `--cwx` to `830px`:

```
@media all and (max-width: 830px){
  :root{
    --cwv: 830px;
  }
}
```

Finally, example's black bar will be set to ½ of `--cwx`, thus ½ of viewport width, but not less than ½ of `830px` *(=`415px`)*:

```css
:root{
  --cwv: 100vw;
}
@media all and (max-width: 830px){
  :root{
    --cwv: 830px;
  }
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

:root::after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: black;
  height: 10px;
  width: calc(var(--cwv) * .5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use media queries for window size like this below

```
@media screen and (min-width : 830 px) {

  /* your code */

 }
```